# Regexp in postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql

What means `E` here:

```
regexp_replace('foobarbaz', 'b(..)',  E'X\\1Y', 'g')
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [regexp match operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP):

```
select *
from mytable
where col ~ '^.{3}(\d)'
```

The `E` denotes a [String Constant with C-style Escape](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS)